# "AND" fails in Excel 2013 conditional formatting formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013, conditional-formatting

I wish to colorize rows conditioning by two columns, e.g., D is date formatted and E contains some plain text, and I want to find out those rows D is earlier than today and E doesn’t equals to "XYZ".

I used formula to determine which cells to format. I wrote the formula like this:

`=AND(TODAY()>=INDIRECT("D"&ROW()), INDIRECT("E"&ROW())<>"XYZ")`

which does not work…

I separately tried each condition and both worked fine:

`=TODAY()>=INDIRECT("D"&ROW())` can find the matching rows as well as `=INDIRECT("E"&ROW())<>"XYZ"`.

However, it fails when I just wrap `AND` closure around each:

```
=AND(TODAY()>=INDIRECT("D"&ROW()))

=AND(INDIRECT("E"&ROW())<>"XYZ")
```

neither of the above works for me. It seems that the combination of `AND` and `INDIRECT` always fails. Since I tried `=AND(TODAY()>=DATEVALUE("2017/5/16"))` which works fine.

I also tried `IF` function, nor does it help:

`=IF(TODAY()>=INDIRECT("D"&ROW()), IF(INDIRECT("E"&ROW())<>"XYZ", TRUE))`

So I am asking for your kind help, what is the correct formula?

Comment: You are using a mix of straight double quotes and fancy opening / closing double quotes in the Indirect function. If you are using the fancy quotes in the Excel dialogs, your formulas will not work. Other than that, don't use Indirect, use relative references instead, if you just want to refer to a different cell in the same row.

Comment: @teylyn, Actually I typed correct quotes in the excel formula input, and I messed them here when I typed the question, sorry for misleading..... I'm referencing to two different cells in each row, so I am not sure how to do that..... Ross's answer is good but I don't know how to avoid changing the contents of column C when I apply the cell format to the entire column..... Also I found the formula does work in cell valuing, rather than in the cell filtering.....

Comment: Do you know what the $ sign does in a cell reference? Look it up. If you create the format in row 1 and reference $D1 and copy down, it will always reference column D in the current row.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

Edit cell C1 and enter the conditional as

> =AND(TODAY()>=$D1,$E1<>"XYZ")

then copy (or apply it) to the column you want - The relative form works inside conditionals as well.

[image]

Applied to C1:C4 Gives

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you answer :) but I don't know how to avoid changing the contents of column C when I apply the cell format to the entire column..... Also I found the formula does work in cell valuing, rather than in the cell filtering..... Still don't know the reason.....

Comment: @shuangwhywhy: Just highlight the entire column (or all cells you want formatted), and click on conditional formatting, then enter the formula Ross provided - Excel will do the rest :)

Comment: You can cope then Paste Special , Formats or select the cell - click conditional formatting, Edit and then set the Applies to the range you want it to apply to.  I have had problems with complex formulae in conditionals - sometimes I see they work when I first switch to the tab - then all go white  - I've learn't to keep them a bit simpler